# How to correctly call base class constructor

Tags: php, constructor

Base class:

```
abstract class AbstractHandler {
    use FeedbackTrait;

    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;
    /** @var SessionInterface */
    private $session;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManager    $entityManager
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager,
        SessionInterface $session
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager() {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return FlashBagInterface
     */
    protected function getFeedback() {
        /** @var FlashBagInterface $feedback */
        $feedback = $this->session->getBag('boltforms');

        return $feedback;
    }
}
```

Then, in the member class I have its own constructor. But I can't get how to properly call the base class contructor.

```
class bigbrotherHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    //custom class vars

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //custom declarations
    }
}
```

PhpStorm says `Required parameter $entityManager missing`. But how do I mention this parameter here? If I go with `parent::__construct($entityManager);`, it says `Undefined variable $entityManager`. If I just copy the data from the braces in the base class constructor, it also gives all sorts of errors. How can I properly call my base class constructor in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call parent constructor with parameters as it has been declared in your abstract class.

```
class bigbrotherHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager,SessionInterface $session) {
         parent::__construct($entityManager, $session);
         //custom declarations
     }
 }
```

BTW think about making "FeedbackProvider" as a standalone service and injecting this service into another services via constructor or method injection (not via setter).

Comment: Thanks. But in this case I have to include `EntityManager` and `SessionInterface` to my member class as well (via `use` statements), and then isn't it the same as to make everything as one class? As for `FeedbackProvider`, it won't be there at all, it's a rudiment from the script I'm basing mine on.